# How can I select users that are not members of any user groups?

Tags: templating, users, user-groups

I'm struggling to find a way to use `craft.users` to select all users that are not members of any groups. Looking at the User Element Type both the `groupId` and `group` parameters are used to perform additional queries which will return nothing unless a valid group Id or handle is provided... I think.

Is it possible to find users not in groups or will I have to do this post retrieving all users... I need to paginate the results so this is not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

You could get the IDs of all users belonging to a group, and use these IDs prefixed with `not` as the `id` parameter in a second `craft.users` ElementCriteriaModel:

```
{% set userIds = craft.users.group('group1, group2, group3').ids() %}
{% set users = craft.users.id('and, not ' ~ userIds|join(', not ')) %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible, exactly for the reasons you provide: while other criteria accept 'not X', group and groupId explicitly add andWhere criteria with the Ids found with ids or handles.

You could make a plugin that returns an array containing all users without a user group, but maybe that's a bit far fetched. I do think that's the only way (for now), if you don't want to do it post retrieving ...