# Get entries NOT related to categories

Tags: relations

is it possible to grab all the entries in a section that arent related to a category?

So something like

```
craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo('not',category)
```

Doesnt seem to work but is there some other syntax?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do it in a single query, [Marion's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/10460/45) is probably the best.

Otherwise, you could do something like this:

```
{% set idsHavingCategory = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(category).limit(null).ids() %}

{% set omitIds = 'and, not ' ~ idsHavingCategory|join(', not ') %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').id(omitIds) %}
```

Inspired by this article, which shows how to (1) grab ids, and (2) query against them:

> http://webstoemp.com/blog/manipulating-craft-elementcriteriamodel-with-twig/

Also references related solutions found in these answers:

- https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4930/45
- https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4573/45

Comment: I know, old question. But any idea how to combine this with a separate query? I'm looking to list entries that either do not have a category, or a specific category. It's proving to be quite a challenge.

Comment: @Athoxx If you want to merge two queries, here is an [old article](https://www.webstoemp.com/blog/manipulating-craft-elementcriteriamodel-with-twig/) (it describes Craft 2) which does a great job of explaining the basic concept. Perform both queries and get **ids**, then use the IDs in a follow up query.

Answer (score 5):

I got this to work with [search](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching):

```
{% set uncategorizedEntries
  = craft.entries.section('news').search('-category:*') %}
```

Here `category` is the category field. You are searching everything in `news` which does *not* have a `category` field that matches `*`.

Comment: hmm yea i guess that would work but i cant imagine thats very performant.  Hoping theres a more direct route to get this to work but maybe not yet.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach -- that might work for you -- is to filter on the output, rather than the query. For instance, using this query:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news') %}
```

Output using this loop:

```
{% for entry in entries if entry.category is empty %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

YMMV

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help much, but I did something similar with:

`{% set allNews = craft.entries.section('news') %)`

Then:

`{% for entry in allNews.id("not #{category.id}")` ... `{% endfor %}`

Hope that helps in some way.

Comment: On second thought, I don't think this is going to be what you're looking for. I'll leave it though, in-case it helps in some other way.

Comment: yea thats not really what i need i need to fet all the entries not in a category