# List entries without specific tag

Tags: tags, channels, tag

I am trying to output a list of entries from a channel section that DO NOT have a certain tag.

I am able to output the entries that have the tag assigned by setting the tag as a variable and using `relatedTo` to filter the entries out. For example:

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.search('All-Stars').first() %}

{% if tag %}
{% set relatedEntries = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(tag) %}
{% endif %}
```

What is the best approach to output entries without the tag?
I've tried the following:

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.search('All-Stars').first() %}
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('news') %}
{% set taggedEntries = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(tag) %}
{% set untaggedEntries = allEntries|without(taggedEntries) %}
{% for feedItems in untaggedEntries.limit(5).offset(1) %}
```

This however doesn't work and throws out some errors, the first being:

*array to string conversion*

**craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(525)**

`$message = sprintf('Impossible to invoke a method ("%s") on a %s variable ("%s")', $item, gettype($object), $object);`

I tried many other ideas like `.relatedTo('not' ~ tag)` and `|without` with no avail.

Is it something obvious I am missing or more advance than that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like following reducing the tagged entries into IDs that you then filter against (see [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10456/get-entries-not-related-to-categories/10479#10479)):

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.search('All-Stars').first() %}
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('news') %}
{% set taggedEntries = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(tag).ids %}
{% set omitIds = 'and, not ' ~ taggedEntries|join(', not ') %}
{% set untaggedEntries = craft.entries.section('news').id(omitIds) %}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!