# Sorting with reverse relationship

Tags: craft3, relations

I have a overview page that combines with two sections (documentation and galleries). Those two sections are attached to a parent Event. So you can select in the event entry a gallery or a documentation entry.

Question: How can i display those in order of the event's entry event day?

```
{% set entryGalleryIds         = craft.entries.section('gallery').ids() %}
{% set entryDocumentationIds   = craft.entries.section('documentation').ids() %}

{% set allEntryIds = entryGalleryIds|merge(entryDocumentationIds) %}

{% set allEntries = craft.entries.id(allEntryIds)|batch(3) %}
```

...

So i'm looking like something as:

`{% set allEntries = craft.entries.id(allEntryIds).orderBy('events.eventDate desc')|batch(3) %}`

Note: When i first query all the projects and then query the related galleries the sorting is gone, because of my id(allEntryIds) filter.

Comment: And you can't start at the events, looping through them (sorted) and output related galleries or documentations?

Comment: Hi Urs, this is an option, but  a) it means entries without a parent won't be show (also not on the end) and b) it feels like bad programming do it this way.

Comment: Well, if they don't have a parent, they don't have a date to sort by either. So you could output the "orphans" at the end https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10456/get-entries-not-related-to-categories